# OS X Yosemite freezes randomly, absolutely everything hangs (screen, trackpad, keyboard, sound, applications, rtc.)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, performance

I'm running OS X Yosemite on an Early 2015 MacBook Pro Retina, 512GB.

According to the title: "OS X Yosemite freezes randomly, absolutely everything hangs (screen, trackpad, keyboard, sound, applications, rtc.)" this started happening when I started to keep Skype in the background, and maybe play Minecraft (don't judge.) But this happens outside of Minecraft, and only happened 2 times by the time I wrote this.

Here's the log from the boot before this crash, to the boot after the crash: http://pastebin.com/wqUEArAS

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this snippet, it is stuck with the

```
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist, error = 2: No such file or directory
```

Try to repair it by running Java Update.

If that does not help you need to repair your installation using the <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: Well, does Skype use Java? That's just Minecraft.

Comment: I do not know if Skype uses Java, but someone on your system is.

Comment: Nope, only user.

Comment: Run the system profiler called EtreChek and publish it. http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pNPnMqTJ

Comment: OK got it, so what do we see there? Ignore the 2 files named com.apple.mtrecorder.plist and the  com.apple.spirecorder.plist they do nothing to your system. You can actually delete them if you want to. You have a trial version of /Applications/Textual 5 Trial.app auto starting, you might what to disable that. I would try to repair the Java install. And what is it with the "KeepingYouAwake"

Comment: what was this chat thing...

Comment: KeepingYouAwake is an updated version of Caffeine, I deleted it though. Textual is an IRC client, the trial version just disconnects you every 12 hours, and thats the only difference from the paid version. (I use Textual daily)